# Run Powershell Commands from a .bat file in Windows 11

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-11

I use a .bat file to run a Powershell script. This worked in Windows 10, but in Windows 11 nothing happens.

```
@echo off
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=   Please enter Username: %=%
runas.exe /user:%USERDOMAIN%\%INPUT% "powershell.exe  -WindowStyle hidden C:\Toolbox\Main.PS1"
set INPUT=
```

I have put in my credentials (it does ask for login and password). Normally it would run the power script with my uplift account and launch a box for me. Now it appears the script is not running at all.

How can I fix this?

Comment: For troubleshooting, I suggest replacing `-WindowStyle hidden` with `-NoExit`, so as to make the PowerShell command run visibly and to keep its window open, so you can examine error messages, if any.

Comment: As implied by Max' answer, the [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies)  may be the problem. Unless execution policies on your system are GPO-controlled, you can enable script-file execution ad hoc by placing `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` before `-WindowStyle hidden`

Answer (score 0):

This is a known MS bug tracked here:

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/12464

There is also a longish work-around there if you need it.

I was looking for a solution to a similar problem myself and, sadly, only found the above discussion.

EDIT: this basically means that your script may be running, just the window isn't getting hidden as expected. Hopefully I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Note that nothing in the question suggests that Windows Terminal is involved, and the problem is that it "appears the script is not running at all." If the problem were that the PowerShell process - designed to run _invisibly_ due to `-WindowStyle Hidden` - does _not_ get hidden, the fact that it is running would be obvious.

Comment: If the OP used `-WindowStyle Hidden` _mistakenly_, then the choice of default terminal application would make a difference: With the console host (old-style console windows), a console window would briefly flash and then get hidden. With WT (Windows Terminal), a window would briefly flash and then get _minimized_ (as of this writing) - that is what the linked GitHub issue is (now) about. There's also a PowerShell-specific issue at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3028

Answer (score -4):

you can use save the your file execution command in the .bat file (as shown below) with `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` and if you click on .bat, it will call the PowerShell file and start to execute.

```
@echo off
 
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\PowerShell\example.ps1'"
 
TIMEOUT /T 10
```

Comment: It should be `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\PowerShell\example.ps1`, but good point that the [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies)  may be the problem.